# How can I retrieve the title of the action button that has been clicked?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I am currently building an android app which needs to work through notification bar's action buttons.

I have added the notification bar and the action buttons. I have also added a `BroadcastReceiver` to perform some action on button click. My problem is that the actions are performed based on the title of the action button clicked. Please guide me in how to get the title of the clicked button.

This is my notification creation code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(AppConstants.YES_ACTION);

    // Open receiver
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //Create Notification using NotificationCompat.Builder
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            // Set Icon
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            // Set Ticker Message
            // .setTicker(getString(R.string.notificationticker))
            // Set Title
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            // Set Text
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.notificationtext))
            // Add an Action Button below Notification
            .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Action Button", pIntent)
            // Set PendingIntent into Notification
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            // Dismiss Notification
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    for(int l = 0; l<btnNames.length; l++){
        if(!btnNames[l].isEmpty()){
            builder.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, btnNames[l],pIntent);
       //     intent.putExtra("Btn"+(l+1), btnNames[1]);
        }
    }

    // Create Notification Manager
    NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Build Notification with Notification Manager
    notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Below is the broadcast receiver code:

```
public class notificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String notificationAction = intent.getAction();

        //the title retrieval code goes here

        if(notificationAction.equals(AppConstants.YES_ACTION)){
            //some work is done here
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: btnNames is a String array. I am using these as my action button names. It is loaded dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step #1: Move all of your `Intent`/`PendingIntent`/`Notification` creation logic inside of the loop

Step #2: Put an identifier of the action button in as an extra to the `Intent` that you use for the `PendingIntent`

Step #3: Use a distinct number for each `PendingIntent` for the second parameter to the `getBroadcast()` method, so you get different `PendingIntent` instances for each

Step #4: Have your `BroadcastReceiver` read the extra to determine the action that was clicked

Or...

Step #1: Move all of your `Intent`/`PendingIntent`/`Notification` creation logic inside of the loop

Step #2: Use a unique action string in each of the `Intent` objects

Step #3: Have your `BroadcastReceiver` read the action string to determine the action that was clicked

Or...

Step #1: Use different `BroadcastReceivers` for each action button

Comment: This worked for me. I am able to get the action button to run a method. Thanks.